# Adding product short-description on product review page

Tags: theme, template

I have used

```
$_helper->productAttribute($_product, nl2br($_product->getShortDescription()), 'short_description');
```

in catalog/product/view.phtml to show the product short description.

Its showing in single product page but not in product review page though enabling Template Path Hints shows they both come from view.phtml

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

You need to re-write class Mage_Review_Block_Product_View and update below function:

```
protected function _toHtml()
{
    //$this->getProduct()->setShortDescription(null); // comment out this code. it is setting short description value to null

    return parent::_toHtml();
}
```